# c++ memory write bytes to address with Windows kernel driver

Tags: c++, memory, kernel, driver, memory-mapped-io

so I will explain what im trying to do and i wanna understand why its not working for me,

I found an Address from CE : which is: `0x04013118` with value an array of bytes: `DC 04 00 00 04 02 00 00`

What im trying to do is write memory with kernel driver to this address a new value which is also an array of bytes :
`DC 04 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Here is most of the function im trying to use , but most of the parameters are defined in other classes i cannot provide all of them but i think part of the code ( just im going to put here ) is already enough,

this is part of the MemoryManager.cpp and also BypassMemory.cpp:

```
void MemoryManager::readMemory(PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T BufferSize){
    if(!allIsWell)
        return;

    struct{
        HANDLE ProcessHandle;
        PVOID BaseAddress;
        PVOID Buffer;
        SIZE_T BufferSize;
        PSIZE_T NumberOfBytesRead;
    } input = { processHandle, BaseAddress, Buffer, BufferSize, NumberOfBytes };

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock;

    NtDeviceIoControlFile(m_hDriver, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &ioStatusBlock, MM_READVIRTUALMEMORY, &input, sizeof(input), nullptr, 0);

}

void MemoryManager::writeMemory(PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T BufferSize) {

    if (!allIsWell)
        return;

    struct {
        HANDLE ProcessHandle;
        PVOID BaseAddress;
        PVOID Buffer;
        SIZE_T BufferSize;
        PSIZE_T NumberOfBytesWritten;
    } input = { processHandle, BaseAddress, Buffer, BufferSize, NumberOfBytesWrite };

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock;

    NtDeviceIoControlFile(m_hDriver, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &ioStatusBlock, MM_WRITEVIRTUALMEMORY, &input, sizeof(input), nullptr, 0);


}


bool MemoryManager::search(BYTE * bSearchData, int nSearchSize, DWORD_PTR dwStartAddr, DWORD_PTR dwEndAddr, BOOL bIsCurrProcess, int iSearchMode, std::vector<DWORD_PTR> &vRet){

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION    mbi;
    std::vector<MEMORY_REGION> m_vMemoryRegion;
    mbi.RegionSize = 0x400;
    DWORD dwAddress = dwStartAddr;

    MEMORY_REGION memSectorList[1000];

    int memSectorIndex = 0;
    while(VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, (LPCVOID)dwAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) && (dwAddress < dwEndAddr) && ((dwAddress + mbi.RegionSize) > dwAddress)){
        if(
            (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT) &&
            ((mbi.Protect & PAGE_GUARD) == 0) &&
            (mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS) &&
            ((mbi.AllocationProtect & PAGE_NOCACHE) != PAGE_NOCACHE)
            ){
            MEMORY_REGION mData = { 0 };
            mData.dwBaseAddr = (DWORD_PTR)mbi.BaseAddress;
            mData.dwMemorySize = mbi.RegionSize;
            m_vMemoryRegion.push_back(mData);
            memSectorList[memSectorIndex] = mData;
            memSectorIndex++;
        }
        dwAddress = (DWORD)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    std::vector<MEMORY_REGION>::iterator it;
    int memSectorCount = memSectorIndex;
    memSectorIndex = 0;
    DWORD_PTR curAddr = dwStartAddr;
    while(curAddr < dwEndAddr){
        VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, (LPCVOID)curAddr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
        long regionSizeOrg = mbi.RegionSize;
        long regionSize = mbi.RegionSize;
        if(regionSize > 10){
            BYTE* pCurrMemoryData = new BYTE[regionSize];
            ZeroMemory(pCurrMemoryData, regionSize);
            writeMemory((PVOID)curAddr, (PVOID*)pCurrMemoryData, regionSize);
            DWORD_PTR dwOffset = 0;
            int iOffset = find(pCurrMemoryData, regionSize, bSearchData, nSearchSize);
            while(iOffset != -1){
                dwOffset += iOffset;
                vRet.push_back(dwOffset + curAddr);
                dwOffset += nSearchSize;
                iOffset = find(pCurrMemoryData + dwOffset, regionSize - dwOffset - nSearchSize, bSearchData, nSearchSize);
            }
            delete[] pCurrMemoryData;
        }
        memSectorIndex++;
        curAddr = curAddr + (DWORD_PTR)regionSizeOrg;
        continue;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
int MemoryManager::find(BYTE *buffer, int dwBufferSize, BYTE *bstr, DWORD dwStrLen){
    if(dwBufferSize < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    DWORD  i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < dwBufferSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < dwStrLen; j++){
            if(buffer[i + j] != bstr[j] && bstr[j] != '?')
                break;
        }
        if(j == dwStrLen)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


DWORD MemoryManager::dRead(DWORD base){ 
    readMemory((PVOID)base, &_d, 4);
    return _d;
}

void MemoryManager::dWrite(DWORD base){
    writeMemory((PVOID)base, &_d, 4);
}
/* these are in bypassmemory.cpp */
void BypassMemory::init(){
    viewWordBase = getAddr(); // = works and gets Addrs = 0x04013118

    if(viewWordBase){
        std::cout << "found addr : " << termcolor::green << std::hex << viewWordBase << std::dec << termcolor::reset << "\n";
    } else{
        std::cout << termcolor::red << "View World Not Found ! \n" << termcolor::reset;
        return;
    }
    // so basiclly my addres = 0x04013118 and value of it = DC 04 00 00 04 02 00 00
    BYTE writePattern[] = { 0xDC, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; 
    //const char* writePtr = "DC 04 00 00 00 00 00 00"; // i tried also this but didn't work

    MemoryManager->writeMemory((PVOID)bypassAddr1, &writePattern, sizeof(writePattern)); // i write to the base addres ( 0x04013118, new val = DC 04 00 00 00 00 00 00)

    //MemoryManager->writeMemory((PVOID)bypassAddr1, &writePtr, sizeof(writePtr));

}

DWORD BypassMemory::getAddr(){

    BYTE pattern[] = { 0xDC, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 };
    std::vector<DWORD_PTR> foundedBases;
    MemoryManager->search(pattern, sizeof(pattern), 0x04000000, 0x05000000, false, 0, foundedBases);
    std::cout << "founded bases size: " << termcolor::green << std::hex << foundedBases.size() << std::dec << termcolor::reset << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < foundedBases.size(); i++){
        DWORD cand = dGet(foundedBases[i]); // this reads inside the address purpose to check
        std::cout << "founded bases addr: " << termcolor::green << std::hex << foundedBases[i] << std::dec << termcolor::reset << "\n";
        return foundedBases[i];
    }
    return 0;

}

int main()
{

    int Pid = ProcManager::getAowProcID();
     

    pMemoryManager->init(Pid, true);


    BypassMemory->init();

    return 0;
 }
```

this is the MemoryManager.h: ( if someone interested )

```
#define MM_DEVICE_TYPE 0x9999
#define MM_CTL_CODE(x) CTL_CODE(MM_DEVICE_TYPE, 0x800 + x, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
#define MM_READVIRTUALMEMORY MM_CTL_CODE(56)
#define MM_WRITEVIRTUALMEMORY MM_CTL_CODE(57)

typedef struct _MEMORY_REGION{
    DWORD_PTR dwBaseAddr;
    DWORD_PTR dwMemorySize;
}MEMORY_REGION;

class MemoryManager{
public:
    MemoryManager();
    ~MemoryManager();


    HANDLE m_hDriver = nullptr;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    int processId = 0;
    bool allIsWell = false;
    PSIZE_T NumberOfBytes = nullptr;
    PSIZE_T NumberOfBytesWrite = nullptr; // created by oday

    DWORD _d;
    float _f;
    int _i;

    BYTE* _b = new BYTE[1];


    int _dw = 1245; // created by oday

    void init(int pid, bool debug);

    bool connectToDriver(std::string m_strDeviceName);

    void readMemory(PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T BufferSize);

    void writeMemory(PVOID BaseAddress, PVOID Buffer, SIZE_T BufferSize); // created by oday

    bool search(BYTE * bSearchData, int nSearchSize, DWORD_PTR dwStartAddr, DWORD_PTR dwEndAddr, BOOL bIsCurrProcess, int iSearchMode, std::vector<DWORD_PTR>& vRet);

    int find(BYTE * buffer, int dwBufferSize, BYTE * bstr, DWORD dwStrLen);


    void dWrite(DWORD base); // created by oday

    DWORD dRead(DWORD base);
    float fRead(DWORD base);
    int iRead(DWORD base);
    BYTE* bRead(DWORD base);

};


extern MemoryManager* pMemoryManager;
```

The interesting part lays in this:

```
BYTE writePattern[] = { 0xDC, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
pMemoryManager->writeMemory((PVOID)bypassAddr1, &writePattern, sizeof(writePattern));
```

I successfully read the address at 0x04013118 from the search function from the current pattern, and everything is fine, but when i try to write to this address with this what i mentioned here up
nothing happens in the memory, and the value doesn't change, does anybody have an idea why nothing happens and the memory doesn't change? im pretty sure my kernel driver has nothing to do with this because its vuln and it has permissions to read and write.

Comment: Did you consider other parties of the application continuously re-writing that specific memory location?

Comment: @Trickzter
Yes I considered everything, and somehow i tested now to write with the normal 
writeprocessmemory like this:
WriteProcessMemory(ProcManager::hProcess, (PVOID)bypassAddr1, &writePattern, sizeof(writePattern), NULL);
and it worked do you know why its not working on my driver writememory function?

Comment: There may be multiple reasons why it does fail. Is your `allIsWell` variable maybe false? Or does `NtDeviceIoControlFile` fail?`I suggest you attach the CE debugger and try to find out "what writes to this address" of your desired memory location.
If the debugger registers the write then you at least know it came through.

Comment: @Trickzter Never mind i take back what I said eariler the write process memory aswell didn't work just noticed now its something weird with the game it self, anyway 
I think it has something to do with how im writing to the memory you think its right what i did to write an array of bytes to that address? , imt attaching ce debugger and looking now it seems nothing gets writed..

Comment: I am not that much into windows driver development, but a common problem with that situation is that the memory page protection bits are not properly set. Try to use VirtualProtect to ensure that the page is writable and reset the bits afterwards.

Comment: @Trickzter i  attached Ce debugger to see what writes or access the address, even though i read and find this address it doesn't show anything in there, and also when i use the writeprocmem or my writemem functions from driver or c++ nothing happens it doesn't appear that its even writing to the address, I cannot figure it out why, if it had something to do with my coding/driver then why the WriteProcessMemory doesn't work either? i gave the proc handle PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, cannot figure this out.

Comment: I still recommend you try out the memory protection with VirutalProtect I suggested earlier

Comment: @Trickzter I think you are right, it has something to do with changing write/read protection to the address/memory i cannot figure out what is it though if u could give me hints.

Comment: @Trickzter could you guide me with sample implementation of the virutalprotect with my code? haven't used it before..

Comment: The documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect is pretty self-explanatory. Just define your desired page access rights (r/w for example) and provide a dword to safe the current virtual page settings. After you are done, reset the memory page with the access rights you obtained through your first VirtualProtect call.

Comment: DWORD oldprt;
 VirtualProtect((PVOID)(0x04013118), 4, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldprt);
 pMemoryManager->writeMemory((PVOID)bypassAddr1, &writePattern, sizeof(writePattern));
 VirtualProtect((PVOID)0x04013118, 4, PAGE_READONLY , &oldprt);


@Trickzter I did something like this and also nothing happened , it didn't write to the memory ..

Comment: The size of `4` does not fit your byte array which is 8 bytes in size.
When you modify the memory with `WriteProcessMemory` make sure you capture all function call results to ensure that everything worked fine. So check the results of OpenProcess,VirtualProtect, WriteProcessMemory and so on.

Additionally keep in mind that you need to use `VirtualProtectEx` if you are trying to modify page bits of a `foreign` process. A normal call to `VirtualProtect` only modifies the bits of the associated page within YOUR current process, not the target process.

I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: @Trickzter Bro you are amazing, it worked with VirtualProtectEx and 8 bytes , thanks this gave me understanding of alot of concept and understanding !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will draw a short conclusion for others having the same problem.

The main problem was that the author was unable to write to a specific memory location within a processes memory.

With the help of the windows API function `VirtualProtectEx` the author was able to change the virtual memory page access bits to allow writing to the memory page of the desired memory address.

The procedure includes:

1. Calling `VirtualProtectEx` to enable writing to the memory page
2. Writing to the specific memory location within that page
3. Reset the page access bits with another call to `VirtualProtectEx`